# Java values injection in bean's constructors

Tags: java, spring

I have the some good working code like:

// SpringConfiguration.class file

```
package com.yet.spring.core;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;

@Configuration
public class SpringConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    public Client client(String id, String full_name) {

        return new Client(id, full_name);

    } //END: Client()

} //END: class SpringConfiguration
```

Now, I can request the bean "client" with constructor values by:

```
 public final static ApplicationContext app_context =
            new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringConfiguration.class);

new_client = (Client) app_context.getBean(Client.class, "1", "John Smith");
```

How to do this by XML configuration file? Can "constructor-arg" be used only for static values or beans?

Comment: You should not do it this way.  It's a profound misunderstanding of dependency injection and how Spring should work.  Spring prefers annotations over XML.  You should not be doing this in XML anymore.

Comment: you may find this helpful - https://www.baeldung.com/constructor-injection-in-spring

Comment: The alternative is 

new_client = (Client) app_context.getBean("simple-client", Client.class);
new_client.init("1", "John Smith");

But is the potentialy bad way...

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use XML then it also supports constructor injection and it works for both primitive types, expressions and beans.

```
<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
  <constructor-arg index="0" ref="dataSource"/> <!-- bean with id dataSource is defined in the same XML earlier -->
</bean>
```

If you need to always get `Client` bean with the same values you can do the following

```
@Bean
@Scope("prototype")
public Client client(@Value("${clientId}") String id, @Value("${clientFullName}") String full_name) {

    return new Client(id, full_name);
}
```

And then define properties `clientId` and `clientFullName` is a property file.
If you need to create `Client` object every time with differetn arguments then you do not need Spring for this at all. You should do

```
new_client = new Client("1", "John Smith");
```

Comment: The idea - request from spring a bean that implement IClient interface and set him fields. At the top I have given an fully working example but it works with annotations. XML may be more helpful in some cases like own framework that use some implementation of the IClient and configures for differet tasks by the XML configuration file. 

We can use @Value annotations for direct member fields initialization by values from differet sources like property files or system configuration. I want to initialize him by inject this values direct to object constructor.

Comment: @МоеИмяНеизвестно then you'd better create a bean called `ClientFactory` which will have a method `createClient(Stirng, String)`. Then inject that factory bean and call its method to create a client